# How set "args" to the list of files of the current buffer

Tags: vim

In the current buffer I have a list of file paths (one per line). I want set "args" to that file list.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need a script for this, or is a mapping ok, or just a manual command?

Comment: The fastest way. It would be great to do something like :g/\v(.*)/arga \1. Or something like that

Comment: I think this is the command you are looking for `g/^/exe "arga ".getline('.')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
:execute "args ".join(map(getline(1, line('$')), 'fnameescape(v:val)'))<CR>
```

Explanation: `getline(1, line('$'))` will return a list of lines in the current buffer (from the first (`1`) to the last (`line('$')`) line, `map(getline(1, line('$')), 'fnameescape(v:val)')` will escape all filenames in case they contain spaces or other special characters, `join(...)` will join the resulting list by inserting space between every two list items, then it will passed to an `args` command by `execute`.

Comment: Great response. In fact I'm trying to learn a bit of "vim scripting" and this answer gives me many interesting concepts. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In short you could use "getline(1, '$')" instead of "getline(1, line('$'))"  (at least in gvim 7.3)

Comment: @kaptux > In short you could use "getline(1, '$')" instead of "getline(1, line('$'))" (at least in gvim 7.3) /// I know about this but I constantly forget it since some other functions that accept line numbers does not accept line expressions: for example, try any `syn*` function. Using `line()` is safe in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try this series of commands: `ggVGJ"ayy:args` then press ctrl-r, then a

*Explanantion*: `ggVGJ` will join all the lines into a single line.  `"ayy` will yank the new single line into register a.  `:args (filenames)` will set the arguments, and `Ctrl-r, a` will drop the contents of register a into the command you are currently typing.

If you don't want to mess up the current buffer (file you are editing), then yank all the lines into a blank temporary buffer first.

Comment: Fantastic response. I don't know the Ctrl-r commad to drop the contents of a register into the command line but for paths with spaces the other response run perfectly. Thanks.